# Can you return the max value of a column multiple times in multiple rows in a MySQL SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, select, max

When I run the following statement:

SELECT * FROM templates ORDER BY templateID

I get the below:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
| Template| Name      | NumberOfColumns   |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|       1 |     blue  |                 1 |
|       2 |     red   |                 2 |
|       3 |     green |                 4 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

And when I do the following:

SELECT *, max(NumberOfContentBlocks) FROM templates;

I get the below:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
| Template| Name      | NumberOfColumns   |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|       1 |     blue  |                 4 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Is there a SELECT statement that will return the below?:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
| Template| Name      | NumberOfColumns   |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|       1 |     blue  |                 4 |
|       2 |     red   |                 4 |
|       3 |     green |                 4 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a scalar subquery in the select-list:

```
SELECT Template, Name, 
  (SELECT MAX(NumberOfColumns) FROM templates) AS NumberOfColumns 
FROM templates ORDER BY templateID;
```

Scalar means as long as the subquery is guaranteed to return one row and one column, it's okay to put in a scalar context (like one column of the select-list).

Comment: Thank you so much Bill. That is EXACTLY what I needed. It worked perfectly.